# Order an array with arrays inside of it by the first arrays keys

Tags: php

So lets say I have an array that I want to organize by the keys.  I thought I would just use `ksort`, but that does not work on the array below.  Essentially I want to organize it so it would be A,R,Z. if I do `ksort` on this array it just returns 1.

```
array
( 
  [Z] => array
     (
        [dked] => asddadff
        [fettyda] => dfdf
        [feqed] => aasdf 
      )
  [A] => array
     (
        [fdkded] => asddadff
        [athgda] => dfdf
      )

  [R] => array
     (
        [fadfded] => asddadff
        [adfthgda] => dfdf
        [gadfhd] => aasdf 
        [gadfhd] => aasdf 
      )
)
```

Comment: Are you by chance doing `$array = ksort($array)`? Then you're doing it wrong. :P Please always post the actual code that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting 1 as response, then you might be trying this

```
$array = ksort($array);
```

But ksort's return value is true or false, not the sorted array.

```
ksort($array);
print_r ($array);
```

This is enough. `ksort` receives the parameter as a reference, so you don't want to assign it back.

Read more here. [ksort](http://in.php.net/ksort)

Answer (score 1):

sample working code:

```
<?php
$var = array('Z'=>array('dked'=>'asddadff','fettyda'=>'dfdf'),'A'=>array('fdkded'=>'asddadff','athgda'=>'dfdf'),'R'=>array('fadfded'=>'asddadff','adfthgda'=>'dfdf'));
ksort($var);
print_r($var);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array declaration needs strings for the indices and values. Also notice the use of commas:

```
array
( 
  "Z" => array
     (
        "dked" => "asddadff", 
        "fettyda" => "dfdf",
        "feqed" => "aasdf",
      ),
  "A" => array
     (
        "fdkded" => "asddadff",
        "athgda" => "dfdf",
      ),

  "R" => array
     (
        "fadfded" => "asddadff",
        "adfthgda" => "dfdf",
        "gadfhd" => "aasdf",
        "gadfhd" => "aasdf",
      )
)
```

Use `ksort` with the above array.

Here's a good reference on array literal notation in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php